# iOS Payment Process - is there a way to include a payload value

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In google, we can launch a purchase and include a payload value. That value is sent to the server and then returned back when the purchase is confirmed. I am looking for a way to do this in iOS.

With iOS, is there a way to include info on the SKPayment or SKProduct? Would it be possible to subclass SKPayment and add additional properties? I would be hesitant to do that in case it doesn't retain the information when the app is fully closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a way similar to payload. Instead I had to go the route of storing the transaction on the server and then reading the transaction back when it was fully purchased.